# How to get Ngrok fixed (static) Port TCP

Tags: ngrok

I am using NGROK for port forwarding and every time it uses to generate for me a random global port

Is there any way to configure it to a specific TCP port to be 7788 for both global and local

Here is what **ngrok** is generating as you can see the global port given is **18147**, but I want it to be 7788 as well and permanently

Web Interface                 http://127.0.0.1:4040                                                                     Forwarding                    tcp://link.ngrok:18147 -> localhost:7788

Please Help me out

Answer (score 0):

This isn't currently possible with ngrok.

It is possible to get a fixed port number by reserving a TCP address with ngrok, but you don't get to pick the port number as ngrok assigns one to you.